# Create list of tuples (in a more elegant way)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a python script to read a file which consists of three columns separated by commas, create a tuple of each line, and make a list of these tuples. With the following script I achieve what I want; I was just wondering whether there is an easier / more elegant approach than writing each of the following steps in a seperate line.

```
import sys
fin=open(sys.argv[1],'r') 

list  = []

for line1 in fin:
        line2 = line1[:-1]
        line3 = line2.split(',')
        line4 = tuple(line3)
        list.append(line4)
print(list)
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python comes with batteries included! If you need to read csv files, just use the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
import sys, csv

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    lst = list(csv.reader(f))
```

Note that this creates a list of lists, if you want tuples for some reason, then

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    lst = [tuple(row) for row in csv.reader(f)]
```

Comment: To add/fix the `csv` module requires one more argument for the `open()`. It is `newline=''` for Python 3 or `'rb'` for Python 2.

Answer (score 4):

Using a list comprehension:

```
lst = [tuple(line.rstrip().split(',')) for line in fin]
```

(Don't name your variables `list`; it shadows the built-in and can lead to unexpected bugs).

Comment: @mgilson: use a proper font if you confuse `l` and `1`! :-P

Comment: I probably have `l` variable names all over my personal code, but PEP8 [warns against it](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid).  I feel like answers from top users should be examples of pristine python code :-) (feel free to clean up any of my less than ideal posts at any time ;-)-- Plus it gets me one edit closer to some badge about editing that I don't know the name of ...

Comment: @mgilson: :-P Okay, if PEP-8 warns against it I'll be more careful in the future..

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for. I will call my lists "List" in the future; will this be fine?

Comment: @Julian -- Usually names like `List` are reserved for classes (as that follows the `CapWords` convention).  I think it's more typical to see something like `lst` for a general purpose throw-away list (that's what I use)

Comment: @Julian: Let me point you too to the [Python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). :-) Simple variables should really use lower_case_with_underscores instead. Use more descriptive names instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- It also warns against using a capital `O` as that looks too much like `0` apparently :)

Comment: @mgilson: less danger of me using that as a variable name; and `l` I only use in a list comprehension looping over lines, come to think of it. Small mercy.

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers as correct as your solution is general and I learned a lot about naming conventions :D
On the other hand, I didn't know that a csv module exists and I really like it. Once again, thank you all for your answers.